# How to create Executable file in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

How can i create Exe file for java program. Do i need to install any software for it, And how to add Icon to that exe file.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=create+a+java+exe 13 million hits.

Comment: Gosh, I wonder why this has never been asked before.

Comment: Mentioned at least once on the duplicate thread (by TRA) but just reiterating that [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can do this.  JWS supports desktop shortcuts and menu items with icons, and works on platforms for which Java is supplied (e.g. Win., Mac. *nix etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use known tools: [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/), [LaunchAnywhere](http://www.zerog.com/iamanual/usermanual_ia55/WebHelp/launchanywhere/abo12e.htm), [JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can but this wouldnt be a real EXE, you will still need to install the JVM to run your app. try [jstart32](http://jstart32.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult. JDK could not do that, you need a third tool to do that. please refer http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html.

Why do you need to do that? maybe you should use c#/vb to program.